# What is Quid Juris?

Tags: kant, critique-of-pure-reason

In his *Critique of Pure Reason*, Immanuel Kant makes the famous distinction between *quid facti* and *quid juris*.

Can someone please explain to me the difference between the two? Also what is the significance of this distinction within the context of Kant's transcendental deduction and even outside of that context in general?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For understanding Kant, it helps to understand that he was a scholar of law before he became a professor of philosophy.

In this textbit, he basically justifies why he uses the term "deduction" in the first place, or rather, he deduces why he is *entitled* to do so.

### Background

In the practice of law, as he explains, there are two different methodologies: you can either rely on *facts*, ie. the empirical evidence available, or you can *deduce* why we are *justified* (or *entitled*) in using certain assumptions because they fit so well with the facts and a certain narrative that they stand **beyond reasonable doubt**.

Generally, *quid facti* means "What [are the] facts?" and *quid iuris* means "What [is your] right?". So more freely translated it is about the question of *evidence* vs. the question of *justification*.

### Deduction in Kant

What he does here is explaining why any proposition *a priori* can only be justified to be assumed as true by means of a *deduction* (*quid juris*) because it  cannot be established as an empirical fact (*quid facti*) by its very nature. In other words, he explains why metaphysical statements have to be justified in a way that their relation to empirical facts and the necessity of them to explain these facts is established beyond reasonable doubt.

The other case where a deduction is necessary is when you want to use a *concept* that is neither based in experience (like all common concepts) nor purely *a priori* (like mathematical concepts - for Kant). As soon as they are not empirical but applied in thinking *about the world* (his *transcendental ideas* world, soul, God, and freedom), we need a *justification* to establish that  we *need* these words to properly think about the world. Only thereby, we are entitled to use these concepts as meaningful.

For more on that matter, see a nice contribution by Pawel Lukow (Kant-Studien 84:2, 204-221).

Comment: "*Talk is cheap, until you talk with a Lawyer.*" (my father had a coffee mug on his desk that said this)

Comment: @ScottRowe Aye, he basically accused all philosophers before him to never have properly justified their metaphysical assertions (insofar they had them) as having a grounding in empirical facts with a deduction to establish their necessity. I guess you need to be a lawyer to build this amount of chuzpe.